# Commenting out a function with NerdCommenter

Tags: vim

Is there a way to do this? I know you can do all the obvious ones like ,c and ,cs

But I don't think there's a binding for commenting out an entire function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From anywhere inside the function, do:

```
va{,c<space>
```

off course, you can map this to something:

```
:map ,o va{,c<space>
```

so pressing `,o` inside a function will comment it (or uncomment it if it is already commented).

Comment: Perfect! The only problem is that it will also hook into if statements and while loops though.

Comment: There are ways to select the whole function but the way you'll choose depends heavily on your coding style and language. For example: try `v2a{`, `v3a{` etc to choose more `{}` levels. See also `:help [[`

Answer (score 1):

## It depends..

It depends on how the function is, and where you are.

```php
public function test()
{
    $name = "whatever";
    $data = array(
        'name' => $name
    );

    return $data;
}
```

---

### Scenario 1: Cursor Line 1 at `public function test()`

> Sequence: `Vj%`

```
V    Start linewise visual mode
j    Go down one line
%    Go to matching closing bracket
```

[image]

### Scenario 2: Cursor Line 3 at `$name = "whatever"`

> Sequence: `va{ok`

```
v    Start visual mode
a{   Arround bracket
o    Exchange cursor from top to bottom of selection
k    Go up one line
```

[image]

---

Then, comment as usual `,,c` depending on your Nerd Commenter mapping.

Answer (score 0):

There are no binding for commenting out the whole function (as far as i know). I think there are couple of ways you can achieve this - for example you can place cursor on the closing bracket, go to the visual line mode, press % key (and select additional line if you place opening bracket in new line) and then use `\cc` for example.

When I want to achieve this i use [textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user) and [textobj-rubyblock](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-textobj-rubyblock) (I am currently programming mostly in Ruby) plugins, which allow me to easily select block of code with `var` and expand it with `ar`. That's quite nice, because I don't need to go to the `end` keyword (in C that would be closing bracket), but I select whole function without moving cursor from the function's body. I have not tried this, but for you [this plugin](https://github.com/michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object) should work. That's not a solution with one binding, but it's quite quick too. I hope this will be usefull for you. :)

Comment: Found my own solution anyway. Place your cursor on the function definition and then v%,c<space>

Would have been good to be able to do that from anywhere in the function though.